# What does "fixed format" mean?

Tags: terminology

Starting in Office 2007, it is possible to save documents in PDF or XPS format.  This is done (programmatically) by calling the method [ExportAsFixedFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238907%28office.12%29.aspx).  Googling has not turned up any definition of "fixed format" that seems compatible with what I know about the PDF file format.  Is there a widely-accepted definition of this term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed format means that the document isn't editable.

When you save it as PDF or XPS it's an export to a format that is only intended for viewing.

(They are of course still editable if you happen to have the right software. For PDF for example that would be Adobe Acrobat Professional, i.e. not the free Adobe Reader.)

Comment: "Fixed format means that the document isn't editable" - do you have a cite? Or know about the source of the term?

Comment: @bmm6o: The term is for example used here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/save-a-file-in-pdf-format-HA010064992.aspx and the similar term "fixed-layout document format" is used here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification#Similarities_with_PDF_and_PostScript

Answer (score 3):

It probably means that these formats do not have formulas or layout engines.
In other words, your values, data, and layout are *fixed*.

CSV would also fit this definition, but it predated the feature.

Comment: More to the point, both PDF and XPS are (originally – at least for PDF) intended as print formats which preserve full fidelity of the document for printing but can be considered “final” or “fixed” in the sense that they aren't meant to be edited anymore.